# Preventing an NSTextField from becoming active (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I want my NSTextFields in my GUI to act like the text fields in the apple finder (the text only becomes active for editing if the text is clicked on when the item is selected).  I tried overwriting the mousedown method of the NSTextField to prevent the selection but this did not do the trick.  What method do I need to override to accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the text field's `editable` property to the "item's" (whatever that is) `selected` property.

Comment: Ah right that sounds much easier then overriding a callback, thanks Chcuk!